# Why was this Ansible question migrated to dba.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, migration

I've just answered [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102066/ansible-how-to-change-mysql-server-root-password-by-reprovisioning-the-server) on dba.stackexchange.com after I followed the migration link from the [ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible) tag on StackOverflow.

The question is pretty much entirely about Ansible rather than anything overly deeply technical about MySQL so it seems wrong to move it to dba.stackexchange.com which doesn't even currently have an [ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible) tag.

Does this look like something that's worth migrating back?